# Different layout on chrome and firefox with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Its the first time i use bootstrap, I use it to create a simple form layout but my problem is that on firefox is not the same as chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNWcN.png "chrome"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/icDDa.png "firefox"

```
<div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
                <div class="col-md-12" onclick="traveler();" style="background-color:#005FB0;height:44px;margin-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;">
                    <span class="bookingFormulaire">1. Who's travelling ?</span>
                    <span class="arrow-up" id="travelerArrow" style="float:right;"></span>
                </div>

                <div id="traveler">


                @for($i = 0; $i < count($passagers); $i++)
                    @if($i==0)
                        <h4>Passager - Adulte (Contact principal)</h4>
                    @else
                        @if($passagers[$i] >= 12)
                            <h4>Passager - Adulte</h4>
                        @elseif($passagers[$i] <= 11 && $passagers[$i] >= 2)
                            <h4>Passager - Enfant</h4>
                        @else
                            <h4>Passager - Bébé</h4>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                            <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Title</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['title_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::select('title_'.$i, array('0' => '-', 'Mr' => 'Mr.' , 'Miss' => 'Miss.' , 'Mrs' => 'Mrs.' , "Ms" => "Ms.") , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::select('title_'.$i, array('0' => '-', 'Mr' => 'Mr.' , 'Miss' => 'Miss.' , 'Mrs' => 'Mrs.' , "Ms" => "Ms.") , null , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div style="height:76px;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
                            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                            <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Name</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['name_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::text('name_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::text('name_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
                            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                            <label>Middle name</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['middlename_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::text('middlename_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::text('middlename_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
                            <i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                            <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Last name</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['lastname_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::text('lastname_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::text('lastname_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if($i==0)
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                                <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Country</label>
                                @if(isset($erreurs['country_'.$i]))
                                    {{ Form::select('country_'.$i, array() , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red' , 'id' => 'country')) }}
                                @else
                                    {{ Form::select('country_'.$i, array() , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'id' => 'country'))}}
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                                <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>State</label>
                                @if(isset($erreurs['state_'.$i]))
                                    {{ Form::select('state_'.$i, array() , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red' , 'id' => 'state')) }}
                                @else
                                    {{ Form::select('state_'.$i, array() , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'id' => 'state'))}}
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div style="height:76px;"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-icon-left">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone input-icon"></i>
                                <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Primary phone</label>
                                @if(isset($erreurs['phone_'.$i]))
                                    {{ Form::text('phone_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                                @else
                                    {{ Form::text('phone_'.$i, '' , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                            <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Date of birth</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['dob_day_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::select('dob_day_'.$i, $day , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::select('dob_day_'.$i, $day , null ,  array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                            <label style="height:22px;"></label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['dob_month_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::select('dob_month_'.$i, $month , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::select('dob_month_'.$i, $month , null , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                            <label style="height:22px;"></label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['dob_year_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::select('dob_year_'.$i, $year , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::select('dob_year_'.$i, $year , null , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div style="height:76px;"></div>
                    </div>

                    @if($i != 0)
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        @if($passagers[$i] >= 12)
                                <div style="height:76px;"></div>
                        @elseif($passagers[$i] <= 11 && $passagers[$i] >= 2)
                            <span class="blueText">This child passenger must be 2 years of age on the departure date and under 12 years of age on the return date to qualify for child pricing on this itinerary.</span>
                        @else
                            <span class="blueText">This baby passenger must be under 2 years of age on the return date to qualify for child pricing on this itinerary.</span>
                        @endif              
                        </div>
                    @endif

                @endfor
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post a live link to it or a jsfiddle?

Comment: try offset rather than empty cols, and make  jsfiddle to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `<div class="row"></div>` around each 12 `col-md-*` column definitions, rather than placing all the column definitions within the the one `<div class="row"></div>`. This will help ensure the rows you are looking to implement are clearing properly. Also I'd avoid setting margin for all sides on any `<div class="row"></div>` as padding/margin for the container/row/col-* is what also assists with clearing and proper responsiveness.

The style for class `.row` that comes with bootstrap.css is:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

In a row definition helps ensure the rows have proper padding on each side and works in conjunction with the col definitions to create gutters. By putting `style="margin:10px;"` you are negating the goal of the class `.row` which can cause various issues in your form.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" onclick="traveler();" style="background-color:#005FB0;height:44px;margin-bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;">
                    <span class="bookingFormulaire">1. Who's travelling ?</span>
                    <span class="arrow-up" id="travelerArrow" style="float:right;"></span>
                </div>
</div>  



<div class="row">           
    <div id="traveler">      
                @for($i = 0; $i < count($passagers); $i++)
                    @if($i==0)
                        <h4>Passager - Adulte (Contact principal)</h4>
                    @else
                        @if($passagers[$i] >= 12)
                            <h4>Passager - Adulte</h4>
                        @elseif($passagers[$i] <= 11 && $passagers[$i] >= 2)
                            <h4>Passager - Enfant</h4>
                        @else
                            <h4>Passager - Bébé</h4>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-select-plus">
                            <label><span style="color:red;">*</span>Title</label>
                            @if(isset($erreurs['title_'.$i]))
                                {{ Form::select('title_'.$i, array('0' => '-', 'Mr' => 'Mr.' , 'Miss' => 'Miss.' , 'Mrs' => 'Mrs.' , "Ms" => "Ms.") , null , array('class' => 'form-control' , 'style' => 'border:1px solid red')) }}
                            @else
                                {{ Form::select('title_'.$i, array('0' => '-', 'Mr' => 'Mr.' , 'Miss' => 'Miss.' , 'Mrs' => 'Mrs.' , "Ms" => "Ms.") , null , array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div style="height:76px;"></div>
                    </div>
```

I didn't add the rest for the sake of brevity, but putting 12 worth of `col-md-*` will help you achieve the layout you are looking. You can nest `<div class="row"></div>` and `col-md-*` within other rows.

If you are still seeing issues with clearing and proper row layout, you can induce clearing at responsive breakpoints using [Responsive Column Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) such as `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>`

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your CSS through a vendor-prefixer? That's where I would start investigating.

Edit: See [link](http://shouldiprefix.com/)